# How do I check if two variables reference the same object in Python?

Tags: python, equality

x and y are two variables.
I can check if they're equal using `x == y`, but how can I check if they have the same identity?

Example:

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = [1, 2, 3]
```

Now `x == y` is True because x and y are equal, however, x and y aren't the same object.
I'm looking for something like `sameObject(x, y)` which in that case is supposed to be False.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You can use `is` to check if two objects have the same identity.

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3]
>>> y = [1, 2, 3]
>>> x == y
True
>>> x is y
False
```

Comment: identity mean id() ?

Comment: `id(x)` returns a value that is unique to `x` for its lifetime, so yes, as long as `x` and `y` exist at the same time. (Two objects that do *not* overlap in time can have the same `id` value.)

Answer (score 3):

Use  `x is y` or `id(x) == id(y)`.
They seem to be equivalent.

`id(object)` returns a unique number (identity) that adapts the philosophy of C-style pointer. For debugging `id(x) == id(y)` is  more convient.

`x is y` is prettier.

---

`==` utilizes equal comparator `object.__eq__(self, other)`

Comment: Avoid using the pattern `id(...) == id(...)` in general. For example, `id(foo()) == id(foo())` could be true without `foo() is foo()` being true: since the lifetime of the objects returned by `foo` may not overlap, Python is free to recycle the `id()` value for use with both objects.