# Python strings and memory optimization

Tags: python, string, memory

This code will load 10000 instances of strings (with same content):

```
lst = []
for i in xrange(0, 10000):
    with open ('data.txt', 'r') as datafile:
        lst.append(str(datafile.read()))
print(lst)
```

**Only by adding code after or before** the above one, i wan't to have the same result as this.

```
lst = []
with open ('data.txt', 'r') as datafile:
    s = str(datafile.read())
    for i in xrange(0, 10000):
        lst.append(s)
print lst
```

This will load only 1 instance of string. => Less memory usage.

In java, there is [String.intern()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern%28%29) ? I look for a python equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`intern()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#intern) to do the same.

> Enter string in the table of “interned” strings and return the interned string – which is *string* itself or a copy. Interning strings is useful to gain a little performance on dictionary lookup – if the keys in a dictionary are interned, and the lookup key is interned, the key comparisons (after hashing) can be done by a pointer compare instead of a string compare. Normally, the names used in Python programs are automatically interned, and the dictionaries used to hold module, class or instance attributes have interned keys.

Store the return value:

```
lst = []
for i in xrange(0, 10000):
    with open ('data.txt', 'r') as datafile:
        lst.append(intern(datafile.read()))
print(lst)
```

Comment: I can't understand i didn't found this before, that's the same name as in Java :)

Answer (score 1):

> In java, there is String.intern() ? I look for a python equivalent.

It is called [`intern()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#intern) in Python, and it's a built-in function.

For further discussion, see [Python string interning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15541404/python-string-interning)