# Making copies in python

Tags: python, list, for-loop, copy

I am trying to copy a list and add it to an existing list of lists.  Say that my original list is `a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` and I would like to append a copy of `a` called `b` to a list of lists called `dataset`. To ensure that `b` is a copy of `a`, `a[0] is b[0]` must be False.  How can I achieve this without the module copy, using the list function and a loop of some sort?

Comment: Why can't you use the copy module? (One guess - this is homework? and if so, I think should be tagged as such?)

Comment: @mfrankli [The homework tag is now officially deprecated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated). But it's a good idea to mention in the post that this is homework.

Comment: I doubt that you can __guarantee__ `a[0] is b[0]` is `False` even with `copy.deepcopy` because implementations can do funny things to optimize immutable objects...

Comment: To underscore @mgilson 's comment - check out [string interning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15541404/python-string-interning).

Answer (score 3):

Here's a hint which should point you in the right direction:

If `a` is a list, then `a[:]` returns a new copy of that list which is distinct from `a`.

```
>>> a = [1, 2]
>>> b = a[:]
>>> a is b
False
>>> a == b
True
```