# Python lists Ids

Tags: python, list

Why is the id is of x changes in the following code while it still has the same value. I expect the id for x and z should be same in this case as the value remains the same at the end.

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3]
>>> z = x
>>> id(z) == id(x)
True
>>> x = [1, 2, 3]
>>> id(z) == id(x)
False
>>> x
[1, 2, 3]
>>> z
[1, 2, 3]
>>>
```

Comment: Because rather than modifying the list in-place, you are actually assigning a new value. Hence the new ID, as it now refers to a different object.

Answer (score 3):

What an object holds has nothing to do with its identity. `id(x) == id(y)` if and only if `x` and `y` both refer to the same object.

Maybe this example helps:

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = [1, 2, 3]
z = y
print x, y, z
y[0] = 1000
print x, y, z
```

which prints this:

```
[1, 2, 3] [1, 2, 3] [1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3] [1000, 2, 3] [1000, 2, 3]
```

y and z both refer to the same object, so modifying one variable modifies the value retrieved by the other, too. x remains the same because it's a separate object.

What you shouldn't forget is that initializing a variable with a literal list (like `[1, 2, 3]`) creates a new list object.

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not the two lists contain the same elements does not imply that they should have the same `id`.

Two variables only have the same `id` if they refer to the same object, which the second `z` and `x` do not:

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3]
>>> z = [1, 2, 3]
>>> x[0] = 999
>>> x
[999, 2, 3]
>>> z
[1, 2, 3]
```

This demonstrates that `x` and `z` are two distinct, unrelated lists.

Comment: Thanks for the response...  do you mean this behavior for list is different for strings/integers.. that's what it appears:           `>>> x = [1,2,3]
>>> y = [1,2,3]
>>> id(x)
47581304
>>> id(y)
3594880
>>> x = "foo"
>>> y = "foo"
>>> id(x)
46246208
>>> id(y)
46246208
>>>`

Comment: @Gaurav: Strings and small integers are subject to interning. See, for example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15541404/python-string-interning

Comment: @Blckknght: D'oh. Copy and paste error. Thanks for pointing out. :)