# Understanding sys.getrefcount

Tags: python

From the doc:

> The count returned is generally one higher than you might expect, because it includes the (temporary) reference as an argument to getrefcount().

And 'till here all is clear to me, infact:

```
Python 3.4.0 (default, Apr 11 2014, 13:05:11) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> x = 'hello'
>>> sys.getrefcount(x)
2
```

But if I do something like this:

```
>>> import sys
>>> x = 'hello'
>>> sys.getrefcount(x)
2
>>> sys.getrefcount('hello')
3
```

I don't understand why I get 3, should I get 2?

Another strange example to me that I have noticed (from a file .py):

```
import sys
print(sys.getrefcount(59587389257548905723958375385))
```

Result ---> 3

Should't it be 1 (according to the doc)?

Comment: Maybe because of `'hello'`?

Comment: but I'm asking the reference count of `'hello'` and only a variable references to it

Comment: You create one reference to `'hello'` for the variable `x` and another reference in the call to `getrefcount`.

Comment: And the result should be 2, don't you think?

Comment: Interestingly, `import sys; sys.getrefcount("hello")` gives `3`, even without assigning to x or anything.

Comment: Yes, I tried with every number and string I could, even without before assignign each of them to a name the result is always 3

Comment: The instance of the string that contains the text `'hello'` is being reused.

Comment: @JeffMercado could you explain better?

Comment: This is just a REPL specific behavior, try with normal Python code and it'll work fine.

Comment: Atleast the first part is probably a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15541404/python-string-interning

Comment: @undefinedisnotafunction what do you mean with normal Python code? I'm get typing normal python code

Comment: @antox In a .py file.

Comment: @undefinedisnotafunction And I tried it, I always get 3