# Identity check on strings returning different output based on assignment method

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I know Python interns certain strings and creates a hash if the string starts with a letter or an underscore and only contains letters, underscores, or numbers as seen in  [Martijn Pieters codementor interview](https://www.codementor.io/python-tutorial/stack-overflow-martijn-pieters-python-optimization).

When assigning individually `s = "$foo"` and  `s1 = "$foo"` `s is s1` returns `False` as expected but using  `s, s1 = "$foo", "$foo"`  `s  is s1` returns `True`.

Why does python behave differently using the different assignments?

```
In [1]: s, s1 = "$foo", "$foo"    
In [2]: s is s1
Out[2]: True   
In [3]: s1 = "$foo"    
In [4]: s = "$foo"    
In [5]: s is s1
Out[5]: False
```

Comment: I think you ought to look at that one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15541404/python-string-interning. it's quite clever what the interpreter can do

Comment: @user3012759, I already have there is nothing there about multiple assignments.

Comment: come to think of it, it's odd that you get s is s1 as false, do you get same results when you put it in one file and just python the file?

Comment: @user3012759, False is the correct output as the string starts with a dollar sign, I get the same results starting a new session for each assignment so there is definitely something in how python handles multiple assignments.

Comment: Just taking a guess here, but could it be that when you do `s, s1 ="$foo", "$foo"` it creates the objects with the same object id?

Comment: @Renier, yes that is what is happening but why it is doing it is the part I don't get.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yep, interning rules escaped me... think we've got an answer now anyway

Answer (score 2):

As Martijn Pieters puts it, in the article you mentioned:

> if a string starts with a letter or an underscore and only contains
>   letters, underscores, or numbers, Python will intern the string

Your particular string contains `$`, so it will *not* be interned - what's happening here is not really related to string interning.

What's happening is that the interpreter is seeing you creating **two references to equal immutable objects**. Since the object types are immutable, a trivial optimization is not to create two objects, but simply choosing to reuse a single one.

To test our theory:

```
In [41]: a=1000

In [42]: b=1000

In [43]: a is b
Out[43]: False

In [44]: a,b=1000,1000

In [45]: a is b
Out[45]: True
```

Notice that this only happens because the interactive interpreter has to compile (and evaluate) each line you enter separately. If you put these statements into a script and execute it, the results are entirely different, because the compiler works on the whole code, and notices it:

```
a=1000
b=1000

print a is b

a,b=1000,1000

print a is b
```

output:

```
True
True
```

Comment: yes, the object is definitely being reused but how is python doing this internally?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham If you're asking *how the CPython compiler figures out that the objects are equal*, I'm afraid that exceeds my knowledge. Maybe someone familiar with the compiler will chime in