# Why is there strange behavior between the IDs of equivalent strings?

Tags: python, python-2.7

From my understanding, if a variable of an immutable type is assigned a value equal to another variable of the same immutable type, they should both be referencing the same object. I am using Python 2.7.6, don't know if this is a bug.

This behaves like I how understood:

```
x = 'ab'
y = 'ab'
id(x) == id(y)
True
```

However, by altering a character, this does not behave:

```
x = 'a#'
y = 'a#'
id(x) == id(y)
False
```

Strangely though, parallel assignment is very different!

```
x, y = 'a#','a#'
id(x) == id(y)
True
```

I do not understand this behavior.

Comment: There's no guarantee that two distinct strings are the same object in memory. Sometimes Python decides to intern them, sometimes not. It's definitely not a bug. I'm not sure why it behaves exactly as it does though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python string interning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15541404/python-string-interning)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're talking about is known as [string interning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning). This is an internal mechanism and there is no guarantee that two distinct strings would be stored in the same place in memory. This is not a bug so don't rely on such behavior. This is in the same general category as undefined behavior in C/C++.

[You may be interested in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15541404/python-string-interning).

While I am able to replicate this behavior in the REPL, the comparison always returns true for me if I put the code in a file and then run it with the interpreter.

By the way there is a way to guarantee that the objects are the same though:

```
>>> x = intern('a#')
>>> y = intern('a#')
>>> x is y
True
```

[More details on the subject can be found in this blog post](http://guilload.com/python-string-interning/).