# if else statement with dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to learn why the following does not work:

I have a dictionary;

```
ex = {'CA':'San Francisco', 'NV':'Las Vegas'}
```

I tried to use `if else` statement to get `'yes'`:

```
>>> if ex['CA'] is 'San Francisco':
...     print 'yes'
... else:
...     print 'no'
... 
no

>>> 
>>> 
>>> if ex['CA'] == 'San Francisco' is True:
...     print 'yes'
... else:
...     print 'no'
... 
no

>>> if ex['CA'] == 'San Francisco' is True:
...     print 'yes'
... 
>>>
```

Here, I don't get `'yes'`

I want to understand why I'm not getting `'yes'`

```
>>> ex['CA'] == 'San Francisco'
True

>>> ex['CA']
'San Francisco'
```

What would be the other ways if I want to use a conditional statement of key of dictionary equals to some value?

Comment: operator precedence:`if (ex['CA'] == 'San Francisco') is True`

Comment: Don't use `is` to compare strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you're comparing `ex['CA']` to `'San Francisco'` (which is OK) and after that you're comparing `'San Francisco'` to `True` which always fails: the result is always false (edited for correctness: the root cause was described wrong, but the fix is the same)

So the code is not doing what you think it's doing.

That'll work:

```
if (ex['CA'] == 'San Francisco') is True:
```

but the pythonic way remains:

```
if ex['CA'] == 'San Francisco':
```

`is True` is valid but I'd reserve it to a very particular usage, when you want to differentiate a non-zero value like `12` (or even `1`) from `True`

other usages make it redundant.

BTW, I can't let you write `if ex['CA'] is 'San Francisco':` and get away with it. You *have* to use `==`. `True` is a singleton so `is` works, but that's not guaranteed for strings, it's implementation dependent. See [Python string interning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15541404/python-string-interning) for more details.

Comment: Side-note: Using `is True` *can* make valid code wrong, it's not *technically* equivalent to simple truthiness testing even for the result of `==` `is True`. `__eq__` is allowed to return any old object, not just `True`/`False`, so if parenthesized as `(ex['CA'] == 'San Francisco') is True` and `ex['CA']` is some custom object with a non-standard `__eq__` that returns, say, `1` on equal, and `0` on not equal, the identity comparison to `True` will always end up being false (1 is equal to `True`, but they're not the same object; if `__eq__` returned `2`, it wouldn't even be equal to `True`).

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with operator precedence, it's just how chaining comparison operators works. Basically, `ex['CA'] == 'San Francisco' is True` is equivalent to `ex['CA'] == 'San Francisco' and 'San Francisco' is True`, just like `a < b < c` is equivalent to `a < b and b < c`

Comment: I knew it was fishy when I wrote that. You're right. I'll fix this, it's wrong... funny thing I thought of `a < b < c` but didn't think of it applying here.