# Python: Detecting input only works for 1 character long strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using python and I'm trying to detect if someone types quit, then stop the program.

Here is my code:

```
print('')

while True:
    inpt = input('>>> ')
    if inpt is 'quit':
        print(':(')
        break
```

I run it and it doesn't work. I proceeded to try this code:

```
print('')

while True:
    inpt = input('>>> ')
    if inpt is 'test':
        print(':(')
        break
```

To see if it has something to do with the word quit, but it didn't work either. Then I tried this code:

```
print('')

while True:
    inpt = input('>>> ')
    if inpt is 't':
        print(':(')
        break
```

And it worked, but I don't know why. Does anyone know how to get quit to work?

Comment: You need to use `==` not `is`. `is` checks for identity, `==` checks for equality. It happens to work for `'t'` because Python interns small string literals.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is-in-python) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15541404/python-string-interning)

Comment: If your question is solved, please choose the answer that solved it instead of editing the subject.

Comment: Side note: to implement a Python interactive console, use the [`code` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/code.html).

Comment: cricket_007 I did it so other people didn't click on this, then realise it was my stupid mistake, having nothing to do with 1 Character Long Strings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`is` is an identity operator. It is used to check if two values (or variables) are located on the same part of the memory. Two variables that are equal does not imply that they are identical. To check if `inpt` contains `'>>>'` string use either `in` or `==` (if you want to be more specific) operator.

```
'quit' == inpt
```

Comment: so if the user typed `don't quit` ?

Comment: Thanks! I feel so stupid... This is my second program. (I can't accept the answer yet)