# Python 3.6 - Writing to a random variable

Tags: python, variables

First of all, apologies for the title, I couldn't think of a better one. What I want to do is to be able to reduce the amount of if statements in my code.
Here is my code:

```
if var is "forwardThrustButton":
    global forwardThrustButton
    forwardThrustButton = res
elif var is "backThrustButton":
    global backThrustButton
    backThrustButton = res
elif var is "leftRotateButton":
    global leftRotateButton
    leftRotateButton = res
elif var is "rightRotateButton":
    global rightRotateButton
    rightRotateButton = res
elif var is "basicShootButton":
    global basicShootButton
    basicShootButton = res
elif var is "specialShootButton":
    global specialShootButton
    specialShootButton = res
elif var is "bombShootButton":
    global bombShootButton
    bombShootButton = res
```

As you can see I have a lot of if statements here, using a string that I have put into a function, and checking to see what that string is. This code works. What I want to do is to be able to pass the name of a variable into the function and just say `var = res`. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use dynamic variables, use a dictionary.

Comment: Could you explain *why* you need a separate variable depending on another variable? This approach leads to the problem that you never know what variables exist at a certain point in time. As @juanpa.arrivillaga already said: use a dictionary. Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables

Comment: Comparing strings with `is` is a bad idea: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504717/why-does-comparing-strings-in-python-using-either-or-is-sometimes-produce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
globals()[var] = res
```

or

```
locals()[var] = res
```

depending on the scope context. But this is very ugly, and it's better to use a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

If you just have a dictionary of all those button values, then you could easily just say

```
buttons["leftRotateButton"] = res
```

that would clean up your code all around too

```
buttons[var] = res
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, use `==` instead of `is`, `is` is an identity testing, you're basically checking if `var` **is** `"forwardThrustButton"`, the very same `str` instance. And the result of this check depends on string interning implementation of a specific Python version. You can check [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504717/why-does-comparing-strings-in-python-using-either-or-is-sometimes-produce) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15541404/python-string-interning) to get more information on the subject.
Apart from that, you can keep a `dict` with all possible button names as keys and buttons as values as mentioned before, or use `exec("global " + var + "; " + var + " = res")`, though latter is quite ugly (but gets the job done).