# 'is' vs '==' in input and assignment

Tags: python

I know that `==` checks the values of the operands, and `is` checks the reference to the same object. However, I can't seem to figure out why the following codes behave differently.

Code1:

```
i=input()
  #Let's say input is Hello
i is "Hello" #Returns False
```

Code2:

```
i="Hello"
i is "Hello" #Returns True
```

Why are the outputs in the two cases different? Isn't assigning "Hello" same as inputting "Hello"?

Comment: Also see the [following post about string interning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15541404/python-string-interning)

Comment: Also see [Understanding Python's "is" operator](//stackoverflow.com/q/13650293)

Comment: Your second example returns true for the reasons outlined in the duplicate post. It is an implementation detail, strings that look like valid Python identifiers happen to be interned for performance reasons.