# Python -- id() builtin function

Tags: python, memory-address

Consider the following:

```
x = 1
y = 1 
print hex(id(x))
print hex(id(y))
```

Output:

```
0x2198158
0x2198158
```

x and y are two different variable that happen to hold the same value. Why is python assigning the same memory location to these two?

Next let us consider strings:

```
x = 'a'
y = 'a'
print id(x) == id(y)
```

Output:

```
True
```

Comment: That's not the `id` of the _variable_. It's the `id` of the object held by the variable. And it's the same object held by both variables.

Comment: You may get detailed info of Python variables and Memory Management in http://foobarnbaz.com/2012/07/08/understanding-python-variables/

Comment: The string version is a different question. It's explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15541404/python-string-interning