# Aliasing in lists

Tags: python

There is some confusion regarding this. Consider this piece of code.

```
>>> g=[[10]*3]*3
>>> f=[[10,10,10]]*3
>>> id(g)==id(f)
False
>>> id(g[0][0])==id(f[0][0])
True
```

Also, consider this piece of code.

```
>>> g=[['Aamir']*3]*3
>>> f=[['Aamir','Aamir','Aamir']]*3
>>> id(g)==id(f)
False
>>> id(g[0][0])==id(f[0][0])
True
```

If `f` and `g` are different objects, then how can their inner elements point to the same memory location?

Comment: It would be redundant to produce a `None` object in different locations and that's why it is declared as a constant

Comment: Remove the None object. Make it 'aamir' in place of None. The result will remain the same.

Comment: Python also has a string pool and detects that you are declaring the same string over and over

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python string interning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15541404/python-string-interning)

Comment: Obligatory string interning post http://guilload.com/python-string-interning/

Comment: You changed your question after getting answers - and now the answers don't make any sense!

Comment: You're testing `'Aamir' is 'Aamir'` or previously `None is None`

Comment: @ThierryLathuille: I've edited my answer to cover both the original and the edited question (and then some :))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As your question evolved, different iterations of it require different answers:

#### `None`

`None` [is a singleton](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/none.html), so all references to it refer to the same object and have the same address. This means that, for a given Python process, `id(None)` always returns the same value. It also means that we can test for `None` using the `is` operator:

```
<expression> is None
```

#### Strings

Strings are subject to [interning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning), where the interpreter folds identical string literals to conserve storage. More on this in [Python string interning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15541404/python-string-interning).

The way this happens to be implemented means that your string example breaks if we replace one of the literals with an expression involving a variable:

```
>>> aami='Aami'
>>> g=[[aami+'r']*3]*3
>>> f=[['Aamir','Aamir','Aamir']]*3
>>> id(g)==id(f)
False
>>> id(g[0][0])==id(f[0][0])
False
```

#### Integers

Interestingly, CPython also chooses to intern small integers:

```
>>> x=1
>>> y=1
>>> x is y
True
>>> x=100000
>>> y=100000
>>> x is y
False
```

More on this in ["is" operator behaves unexpectedly with integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers).

Concretely, this means that your first example breaks if we try it with much larger integers:

```
>>> g=[[100000]*3]*3
>>> f=[[100000,100000,100000]]*3
>>> id(g)==id(f)
False
>>> id(g[0][0])==id(f[0][0])
False
```

Answer (score 3):

Because `None` doesn't change homes. Every `None` object has the same location. Try

```
>>>check = None
>>>id(check) == id(f[0][0])
```

You'll get:

```
>>>True
```