# Why 'is' return different result for 'same compare' in Python?

Tags: python, compare

I known that 'is' in Python is compare two object's id. But why the same compare will return different result?

Here is a example code for my question. (Python 2 and 3 as same)

```
>>> x = '123'
>>> y = '123'
>>> x is y
True
>>> x *= 100
>>> y *= 100
>>> x is y
False
```

Comment: Fun fact: if Python 3, `import sys.intern as intern`, then `intern(x) is intern(y)` gives `True`; basically you force Python to eliminate duplicates. See [this other dup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15541404/1270789) for more details.

Comment: @KenY-N The marked dupe is the wrong one, the question is about strings not integers; your linked one is better

Comment: @Chris_Rands indeed; there were three distinct dups flagged, including the  one I linked to in the comment above, but for some reason only one is showing.