# for loop with string list and if condiiton not working

Tags: string, python-3.x, for-loop

I am new to programming and python.I've written a simple python program that iterates through a list of fruits and stops when it encounters the fruit `'Banana'`.

```
fruits = ['Orange', 'Mango', 'Grapes', 'Guava','Blue Berry', 'Litchie', 'Banana',
          'Cherry', 'Strawberries', 'Pears', 'Apple']

for x in fruits:
    if x is "Banana"
        print('Here is %s',x)
        break
    else
        print(x)
```

The above script fails with invalid syntax. I tried different options such as `x == 'Banana'`: but the same error message is displayed. What's wrong here?

Comment: Why do you write it in one line?

Comment: you are missing the `:`. it should be `if x == 'Banana':` (the same goes for `else:`). and do not compare strings with `is`. as a beginner you will get surprising results ([string interning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15541404/python-string-interning)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put Colon after at the end of if and else.

```
fruits = ['Orange', 'Mango', 'Grapes', 'Guava','Blue Berry', 'Litchie', 'Banana',
      'Cherry', 'Strawberries', 'Pears', 'Apple']

for x in fruits:
if x is "Banana":
    print('Here is %s',x)
    break
else:
    print(x)
```

Comment: ...as i mentioned: comparing strings with `is` is usually not a good idea! and please fix the string formatting in the `print` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for x in fruits:
    if x == "Banana":
        print('Here is %s'%x)
        break
    print(x)
```