# Get reference to Python dict key

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, pool

In Python (3.7 and above) I would like to obtain a reference to a dict **key**. More precisely, let `d` be a dict where the keys are strings. In the following code, the value of `k` is potentially stored at **two** distinct locations in memory (one pointed to by the dict and one pointed to by `k`), whereas the value of `v` is stored at only **one** location (the one pointed to by the dict).

```py
# d is a dict
# k is a string dynamically constructed, in particular not from iterating over d's keys
if k in d:
    v = d[k]
    # Now store k and v in other data structures
```

In my case, the dict is very large and the string keys are very long. To keep memory usage down I would like to replace `k` with a pointer to the corresponding string used by `d` before storing `k` in other data structures. Is there a straightforward way of doing this, that is using the keys of the dict as a string pool?

(**Footnote:** this may seem as premature optimisation, and perhaps it is, but being an old-school C programmer I sleep better at night doing "memory tricks". Joke aside, I do genuinely would like to know the answer out of curiosity, and I am indeed going to run my code on a Raspberry Pi and will probably face memory issues.)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15541404/python-string-interning or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string-interning explains about python string memory handling & the mechanisms behind it - If I were you I would just not care until its a proofen problem.

Comment: I feel like this is a (very) premature optimization. Have you actually ran into memory issues? if not, don't worry about it and let Python manage its memory.

Comment: Anyway, `v = d[k]` doesn't allocate more memory. It just creates a reference called `v` to whatever `d[k]` points to

Comment: Why do you think that a copy of an existing object would be made when you decide to use it as a key in some dict?

Comment: How would you get into that situation? Where would the two string objects with the same value come from?

Comment: @DeepSpace They didn't say `v = d[k]` allocates more memory and they already said that `v` is only stored once. They're asking about `k` (and its equal string in the dict).

Comment: If you have such large strings as keys to `d`, could you also store `hash(key)`? Then when `k in d` is `True`, store `d2[hash(k)] = v`?

Comment: @quamrana Might cause collisions, though.

Comment: I have accepted the answer below as it provides a direct solution to my problem. However, in practice, I will abandon my "premature optimisation" and incorporate hashes and using a different approach. I do appreciate the comments above, such as "not to worry about it" by @DeepSpace

Comment: @superbrain I got into this situation because the dict is a cache, mapping strings to certain properties. While iterating over new strings (constructed dynamically) I will create a new, fresh cache (dict). Many of the key-value pairs from the old dict will make it to the new dict, hence I found it a waste allocating new space for strings already present in memory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Where does the key `k` come from? Is it dynamically constructed by something like `str.join`, `+` , slicing another string, `bytes.decode` etc? Is it read from a file or `input()`? Did you get it from iterating over `d` at some point? Or does it originate from a literal somewhere in your source code?

In the last two cases, you don't need to worry about it since it is going to be a single instance anyway.

If not, you could use `sys.intern` to intern your keys. If `a == b` then `sys.intern(a) is sys.intern(b)`.

Another possible solution, in case you might want to garbage collect the strings at some point or you want to intern some non-string values, like tuples of strings, you could do the following:

```
# create this dictionary once after `d` has all the right keys
canonical_keys = {key: key for key in d}

k = canonical_keys.get(k, k) # use the same instance if possible
```

I recommend reading up on [Python's data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html).