# In python a='test', b='test'. print(a is b) true, print(id(a) == id(b)) true, print(id(a) is id(b)) false

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
a = "test"
b = a
c=id(a)
d=id(b)

print("a == b:",a == b)
print("a is b:",a is b)
print(id(a), id(b))
print("id(a) is id(b):",id(a) is id(b))
print("id(a) == id(b):",id(a) == id(b))
print(c, d)
print("c is d:",c is d)
print("c == d:",c == d)
```

----------result----------

a == b: True
a is b: True
1843108275696 1843108275696
id(a) is id(b): False
id(a) == id(b): True
1843108275696 1843108275696
c is d: False
c == d: True

Why does id(a) is id(b) have false?
I expecte id(a) is id(b) True

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python string interning](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15541404/11082165) and ["is" operator behaves unexpectedly with integers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/306313/11082165)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`is` compares the memory addresses of the objects a and b. They are different in your case and would be false.

More: The `is` keyword is used to test if two variables refer to the same object.

Docs: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_keyword_is.asp

Answer (score 0):

Even `id(a)` and `id(a)` are different (when compared with `is`) because they are different objects of type `int`. Only very small absolute values of `int` are the same object:

```
>>> int(str(2 ** 6)) is int(str(2 ** 6))
True
>>> int(str(2 ** 16)) is int(str(2 ** 16))
False
```

The `int(str(...))` conversion is needed to prevent interning of identical int literals by Python 3.7+.

The result of `id` is usually a large `int`:

```
>>> id("test")
140023900375784
```

By saying *o1* and *o2* are different objects I mean that the they are not stored at the same memory address.