# Why is the "is" operator behaves differently for strings and lists in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, string

From what I read in the documents,

> `is` operator is used to check if two values are located on the same part of the memory

So I compared two empty lists and as I expected I got `False` as a result.

```
print([] is []) # False
```

But why is it different for strings?

```
print('' is '') # True
```

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/15541404/494134

Comment: If you want to compare _values_, then you should use `==`, not `is`.

Comment: If you want for a fun similar example: `x=1000; y=1000; x is y` ⇒ True, while `x=1000`\n `y=1000`\n `x is y` ⇒ False  (tested on python 3.10.6).

Comment: @spectras is there a typo? Both are same statements right?

Comment: @MaranSowthri first one is typed all on one line. Second one is typed on 3 lines. Other than that they are the same yes.

Comment: @spectras, I'm shocked! But why?

Comment: In short, it comes from the "boxing" of the integers. All python values are wrapped in some object. In the one-liner, python wrapped the value `1000` once and handed it to both `x` and `y` (as `1000` is immutable they can share it). On separate lines, it does the boxing separately so they each get a different box. `is` tests whether the box is the same (as opposed to checking the value inside). Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers for more.

Comment: You should eliminate the `is` operator from your short-term memory.  With the exception of the `None` object, it has almost no useful use cases.