# python check if two objects have same memory address

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am trying to check if two python objects have same memory address

I am trying to do somthing like `a == b`. but its not working.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check if two variables reference the same object in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3647546/how-do-i-check-if-two-variables-reference-the-same-object-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

you can use id to know if they refere to the same object.

```
a= 5
b= 4+1

print (id(a))
print (id(b))
```

[Compare if two variables reference the same object in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445080/compare-if-two-variables-reference-the-same-object-in-python)

[How do I check if two variables reference the same object in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3647546/how-do-i-check-if-two-variables-reference-the-same-object-in-python)