# Why does Python handle '1 is 1**2' differently from '1000 is 10**3'?

Tags: python, reference, semantics, python-internals

Inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11485879/is-it-possible-for-the-python-compiler-to-optimize-away-some-integer-arithmetic) question about caching small integers and strings I discovered the following behavior which I don't understand.

```
>>> 1000 is 10**3
False
```

I thought I understood this behavior: 1000 is to big to be cached. 1000 and 10**3 point to 2 different objects. But I had it wrong:

```
>>> 1000 is 1000
True
```

So, maybe Python treats calculations differently from 'normal' integers. But that assumption is also not correct:

```
>>> 1 is 1**2
True
```

How can this behavior be explained?

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/306313/1008142 - the accepted answer points a relevant section of the Python docs. [edit: sorry, not a dupe; thanks jaapz]

Comment: @RoryYorke essentially, yes, but it does not explain the difference between 1 is 1**2 and 1000 is 10**3

Comment: possible duplicate of [Weird Integer Cache inside Python 2.6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15171695/weird-integer-cache-inside-python-2-6)

Comment: @RoryYorke That answer explains why `1000 * 10**3` return `False`. Because 1000 is to big to be cached. It doesn't explain why `1000 is 1000` returns `True`. 1000 is bigger than 256 and therefore shouldn't be cached. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

There are two separate things going on here: Python stores `int` literals (and other literals) as constants with compiled bytecode *and* small integer objects are cached as singletons.

When you run `1000 is 1000` only one such constant is stored and reused. You are really looking at the same object:

```
>>> import dis
>>> compile('1000 is 1000', '<stdin>', 'eval').co_consts
(1000,)
>>> dis.dis(compile('1000 is 1000', '<stdin>', 'eval'))
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (1000) 
              3 LOAD_CONST               0 (1000) 
              6 COMPARE_OP               8 (is) 
              9 RETURN_VALUE
```

Here `LOAD_CONST` refers to the constant at index 0; you can see the stored constants in the `.co_consts` attribute of the bytecode object.

Compare this to the `1000 is 10 ** 3` case:

```
>>> compile('1000 is 10**3', '<stdin>', 'eval').co_consts
(1000, 10, 3, 1000)
>>> dis.dis(compile('1000 is 10**3', '<stdin>', 'eval'))
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (1000) 
              3 LOAD_CONST               3 (1000) 
              6 COMPARE_OP               8 (is) 
              9 RETURN_VALUE
```

There is a peephole optimization that pre-computes expressions on constants at compile time, and this optimization has replaced `10 ** 3` with `1000`, but the optimization doesn't re-use pre-existing constants. As a result, the `LOAD_CONST` opcodes are loading two different integer objects, at index 0 and 3, and these are two *different* `int` objects.

Then there are optimisations in place where [small integers are interned](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/int.html#PyInt_FromLong); only one copy of the `1` object is ever created during the lifetime of a Python program; this applies to all integers between -5 and 256.

Thus, for the `1 is 1**2` case, the Python internals use a singleton `int()` object from the internal cache. This is a CPython implementation detail.

The moral of this story is that you should never use `is` when you really wanted to compare by value. Use `==` for integers, always.