# Strange problem with array initialization and declaration

Tags: python, arrays

I think I found a strange problem regarding arrays. I initialize an array, array1, with no elements in it, and create another array, say array2, which I initialize to be exactly like array1. This is my code:

```
array1 = []
array2 = array1
```

Now, when I append an element to **array1** and print out **array2**, this appears:

```
array1 = []
array2 = array1
array1.append(0)
print(array2)

>> [0]
```

Why exactly does array2 have that zero that I appended to array1? Why did it update its elements twice? It's like I wrote:

```
...
array2 = array1
array1.append(0)
array2 = array1
...
```

That's very strange in my opinion. Can anybody explain what happened here / what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you are referencing the same object in memory, after the assignment `array2 = array1`.
You can check that these two references refer to the same object by using this code:

```
array1 = []
array2 = array1
array1.append(0)
array2 = array1 # Even if you didn't include this line, the check would still yield True.
print(array1 == array2)
```

When run this outputs `True`:
For more information regarding references and objects check this question [How do I check if two variables reference the same object in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3647546/how-do-i-check-if-two-variables-reference-the-same-object-in-python)

Comment: So basically it is an exact duplicate of that earlier question.

Comment: @usr2564301 I use different code here, from both cited questions.

Comment: @usr2564301 To further adjust it to op's question.

Comment: Everyone's code will be different but the answer is still the same. See [Is it valid to vote to close as duplicate when the questions are at first glance unrelated?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262853/is-it-valid-to-vote-to-close-as-duplicate-when-the-questions-are-at-first-glance/262858#262858) (and many more on [meta]) for a discussion. Do note that "being a duplicate" *in general* is not considered a problem (but in this case it is a straight duplicate IMO).

Comment: @usr2564301 I was just trying to give him a better image, besides when I answered the question was still open. What do you think I should do?

Comment: Thank you so much for your clear explanation. I'm sorry that this is a duplicate and I was unnecessarily wasting your time. I think I just searched badly.

Comment: @Acanum No problem, don't worry, thanks for the accept ;)